# Rails 5 add non persistent ActiveRecord attributes dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 2.3 app I want to upgrade to Rails 5.

In some of my models there are non persistent attributes, i could read and write in my controller that way:

```
  r_v = Model.new
  r_v[:count_all_bqu] = 0
  r_v[:count_all_bsk] = 0
  r_v[:count_all_bmd] = 0
```

I changed the structure because for some reason Rails 5 doesn't process it anymore.

So, I created attr_accessors in my model:

```
  attr_accessor :count_all_bqu
  attr_accessor :count_all_bsk
  attr_accessor :count_all_bmd
```

and replaced the lines above with these ones:

```
  r_v = Model.new
  r_v.count_all_bqu = 0
  r_v.count_all_bsk = 0
  r_v.count_all_bmd = 0
```

So far, no problem.

But there are also things like:

```
  for r in Model.where(condition)
    r_v["count_#{r.b_id}_erg_bst"] = 0
    ...
```

How do I convert "count_#{r.b_id}_erg_bst" to a non persitent attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am sure there is a more `ActiveModel` ([RoR Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_model_basics.html), [API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html) - but it might not be `ActiveModel` but a similar module) way of doing this, with plain Ruby you would do it like this:

```
r_v.send("count_#{r.b_id}_erg_bst=", 0)
```

Basically, you "call" the method `count_..._erg...=` (a method assigning the local variable, defined by `attr_accessor`) with the argument `0`.

For `r.bid == 'my'` it would be the same as calling `r_v.count_my_erg_bst= 0`.

Note that this will only work if something like `attr_accessor :count_my_erg_bst` is part of your class definition.

Otherwise, you can do it more meta-programmingish whith something like `rv.instance_eval { @count_my_erg_bst = 0 }` or, because you need string interpolation
`rv.instance_eval " @count_#{r.bid}_erg_bst = 0 "`

**Note the security implications!** If `r.bid` is provided by the user, it could be something like `"a = 1; system("rm -rf /");"` or other harmful code!

Comment: Thanks Felix! Good idea, unfortunately it didn't quite work for me, because I also would like to make comparisons and additions. However, it took me in the right direction.

I solved it that way now:
I created an ```attr_accessor :z_hash``` in my model, which I fill in the controller with key-value pairs: ```r_v.z_hash["count_#{r.b_id}_erg_bst"] = 0```